# Multi tenant stateful service: service instance per tenant vs partition per tenant

Tags: service-fabric-stateful, azure-service-fabric

We plan on using a stateful service to act basically as a cache for tenant data that is stored externally. Is there much difference in creating a separate service of the same service type for each tenant vs having one service and a separate partition for each tenant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add and remove service [partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-partitioning) of a service on the fly. So using partitions is likely not the way to go if the number of tenants is a variable.

You'll get the most flexibility and scalability if you use a service or even an application per tenant.